# jQuery Ajax post error undefined while submitting second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting undefined while submitting the form second time through ajax.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var site_url = '<?php echo site_url('front/submit_quote'); ?>';

    $('button.showme').click(function(ev){
        var uid = $(this).data('id');
        $('.modal-body').attr("id","ta"+uid);
        var neil = $('#ta'+uid+' textarea').val(uid);
        $('#ta'+uid+' textarea').attr("id","taval"+uid);

        $('.save-data').click( function (e) {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
            var msg = $('#ta'+uid+' textarea').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: site_url, 
                type: 'POST', 
                data: 'id='+uid+'&message='+msg,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Console result:

```
Array (
    [id] => 35
    [message] => 35fffffffffff
)
Array (
    [id] => 35
    [message] => undefined
)
Array (
    [id] => 23
    [message] => 23dfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
)
```

Comment: **$('.save-data').click( function (e) {** this line should be out of  **$('button.showme').click(function(ev){** click event.

Comment: You add up events like this. @AlpeshJikadra is right.

Comment: you need to rethink the login you should not nest the events like this